# Unix IFS unable to set and put key/value data into array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

I have a little bash script that I had working before. Where I used Unix `IFS` to import a key/value from a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash

KEY=/home/myusr/.keyinfo

IFS="
"
set -A arr $(cat $KEY)
echo "This is ${arr[0]}"
echo "This is ${arr[1]}"
```

Input `.keyinfo` file:

```
ABC 123
```

However, I'm trying to get this to work on a different flavor of Linux and I'm getting this error message:

```
./tst3.sh: line 7: set: -A: invalid option
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [arg ...]
This is
This is
```

Question:

- Is this the better way to use `IFS`? Best practice?

I'd like to dump the key/value pairs into an array and then call those out later in my script.

Comment: What does your IFS contain? Can't tell which whitespace is in there.

Comment: You mean my input file? I wanted to the option of creating a key file with either `key value` or `key:value` or `key;value` and whatever was the best way to split those.

Comment: No, I mean what's between the quotes where you define IFS. Anyway, `set -A` is ksh: bash does not have the `-A` option for `set`, as the error indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your code by modifying it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
KEY=/home/myusr/.keyinfo
IFS=$' '  # omitting this line will do too, as IFS is defaulted to space
declare -a arr=($(cat $KEY))
echo "This is ${arr[0]}"
echo "This is ${arr[1]}"
```

Use `declare` to declare variables, not `set`.

`-A` option is for associative array, `-a` for indexed array.

Instead of using `cat` you should consider using: `declare -a arr=($(< $KEY))`

Comment: Isn't `\n` mean newline? I'm getting these results: This is `ABC 123   This is` I have a tab in between my key and value.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help and explanation to using this.